# How do I delete Miis from the Create Mii Fighter tool?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

A friend created an Eldritch abomination as a Mii template for the Mii Fighters.  Now since it's one of the default choices for base Miis. I can't seem to find a way to delete them.

To be clear, I am not talking about the Mii Fighters, but the actual Miis themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to know how to delete a Mii from your Switch console wide rather than just removing them as an option from the game. To do this follow these steps:

> 1. From the HOME Menu, select "System Settings."
>    [image: Image of Switch home screen]
> 2. Scroll down the options on the left and select "Mii."
> 3. Select "Create/Edit a Mii."
> 4. Select "Mii List." Choose the Mii character you want to edit/delete.
> 5. Select "Delete," then "Delete" again.
>
> <sub>[Nintendo Support, How to Edit or Delete a Mii](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22555/%7E/how-to-edit-or-delete-a-mii)</sub>